# Can I change ReceivedBytesThreshold while running?

Tags: c#, serial-port, threshold

I have an external box connected to a serial port (BlueTooth, actually, if that matters).

Some of my communications with the box are short; I think 11 bytes long, while others are long; like 4096 bytes.

Can I change the Serial Port's ReceivedBytesThreshold property from 11 to 4096 and back and so on ?

If so, could someone please point me to some example code that does that ?

My elementary questions are how, when, and where?

Comment: Chances are you won't even need to. Have you tried running as is yet?

Comment: Thanks Jon B, good question. Short answer: no.

Comment: Longer answer: a fake routine that generates one second's worth of purposely bogus data ("Random" and "Next();" and so on) shows that the graphing is "bunching up" instead of smoothly scrolling across the screen. I'm scared that when I put the real data from the Uarts in place of the fake routine that I'm going to get even worse bunching up.